# How to use Glide in Fragment - Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, video-thumbnails, android-glide

I am building a video playing app in Java where I use three Fragments. In one of them I have a list of videos to be played (using a simple ListView widget) where I use a Custom Adapter to pass the titles and the bitmaps thumbnails/uri paths of those videos. When I use Glide to generate and show the bitmaps in the ImageView section of the Custom Adapter, it works (passing only uri paths from Fragment), because the context in the getView() function works as well.

But I want to generate the bitmap thumbnails using Glide in the ListView Fragment, not in the Custom Adapter class, because I need those thumbnails in other Fragments of the app. Unfortunately I didn't managed to create the thumbnails in the ListView Fragment, because the context I am writing at Glide.with() in the onCreateView() function doesn't work!

What is the proper context to be used for Glide in the ListView Fragment to see it and generate the bitmap thumbnails?

I used this code in the ListView Fragment:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap().load(uri)
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                bitmapThumbnail = resource;
            }
        });
```

but it doesn't generate any thumbnails.. :((

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragment you can get the parent Activity Context by calling `getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem wasn't the context I added to Glide.with() section, but the fact that the bitmap generated inside the "onResourceReady(...)" method stays in there and it cannot be used outside the method, only inside and as an argument for an "imageView.setImageBitmap()" method...

As I understood by now, Glide only intermediates between the url/uri/path and the imageView widget, it's not generating any bitmaps outside itself! This is a valuable thing I learned about Glide!

Many thanks for all the help I received!